# grunt failed due to jit-grunt: Plugin for the "help" not found

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-requirejs

[image]
what is going on? i tried adding this below in Gruntfile.js, but it still doesn't work.

```
module.exports =function(grunt){

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        jitGrunt: true
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post your entire Gruntfile to http://pastebin.com/ ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a static mapping to your load-grunt-config task, like this:

```
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
    jitGrunt: {
        staticMappings: {
            default: 'the-name-of-your-grunt-task'
        }
    }
});
```

This link may also help:

http://ia.njamieson.co.uk/2015/03/27/speeding-up-grunt-initial-load-jit-grunt-and-load-grunt-config/